# Get a List of Drive Files Into a Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

```
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1_gA4D7dfybJ60IdfgsnqdfdsgVoo9D76fgsdgf9cqmAnJI7g7');
  var contents = folder.getFiles();
  var file;
  var name;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var date;
  var size;

  sheet.clear();
  sheet.appendRow(["Nome", "Data", "Dimensione"]);

  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    file = contents.next();
    name = file.getName();
    date = file.getDateCreated();
    size = file.getSize();
    id = file.getUrl();

    data = [name, date, size,id]
    sheet.appendRow(data);
  }
};
```

Every time all the data is cleared, after that the data is added from the starting.

`sheet.clear();sheet.appendRow(["Nome", "Data", "Dimensione"]);`

Is there any way to check the data?
if the same data present Already then the function does not work on the row.

If a new record is added, it should also be added, but the function does not start again from one.

If I have 20 PDFs in my folder, and add one more PDF in folder, then add the function 21 pdf and do not run the function from the beginning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Explanation:

The logic behind the following script is the following:

1. We get all the `URLs` of the files that are currently in column **D** of the sheet. These are the `URLs` of the files that have been recorder so far. We can safely assume that the `URLs` are always unique:

   ```
   const aURLs = sheet.getRange('D2:D'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
   ```

2. The second step is to iterate through the files as the original script would do and check if the `URL` of a file is in `aURLs`. If the file `URL` is **not** in `aURLs` or in other words in column **D**, then add it to the `newFiles` array:

   ```
   if(!uNames.includes(name)){
    newFiles.push(data);
    }
   ```
3. After we checked all the files, we can add, after the last row of sheet, **only** the new files:

`sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,newFiles.length,newFiles[0].length).setValues(newFiles);`

---

### Solution:

Manually add the headers in the file for the first time only:

[image: headers]

and then execute the script every next time:

```
function myFunction() {
  const folder = DriveApp.getFolderById('1_gA4D7dfybJ60IdfgsnqdfdsgVoo9D76fgsdgf9cqmAnJI7g7');
  const contents = folder.getFiles();
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  const aURLs = sheet.getRange('D2:D'+sheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  
  const newFiles = [];
  
  while(contents.hasNext()) {
    let file = contents.next();
    let name = file.getName();
    let date = file.getDateCreated();
    let size = file.getSize();
    let id = file.getUrl();
    let data = [name, date, size,id]
    if(!aURLs.includes(id)){
    newFiles.push(data);
    }
  }
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow()+1,1,newFiles.length,newFiles[0].length).setValues(newFiles);
}
```